# C++ difference of "::" and "->"

Tags: c++

I'm just curious whats the difference of `::` and `->` in C++?

Currently studying C++ because I want to study openGL and lots of tutorial in openGL using c++ so I'll just go with language that has many tutorials :)

In `java` or `C#` if you want to call a function or a reserved function you just use "." like for example `text1.getText()`; If you are to convert it to `C++` would that be `text1->getText()`? and what to call them? Title is not appropriate. If `->` is equal to "." in `java` then whats the use of "::"? I believe there are many questions out there like mine but I don't know what to call them so I cant have an accurate information. By the way I found this `::` think while using sfml.

Here is an example

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                // end the program
                running = false;
            }
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized)
            {
                // adjust the viewport when the window is resized
                glViewport(0, 0, event.size.width, event.size.height);
            }

void renderingThread(sf::Window* window)
    {
        // activate the window's context
        window->setActive(true);


        // the rendering loop
        while (window->isOpen())
        {
            // draw...

            // end the current frame -- this is a rendering function 

(it requires the context to be active)
                window->display();
            }
        }
```

window uses -> while sf uses `::`

Comment: `::` is how you get to a static function or field (which don't require an instance of an object), `->` is dereferencing a pointer to get to a function or field (and thus requires an instance, and uses the instance's specific values). Look up C++ operators

Comment: Use `::` to access members by class name, `.` to access by object value, `->` by object pointer.

Comment: No one's explicitly mentioned that the scope resolution operator works for non-static members as well. `auto f = std::bind(&Foo::bar, fooInstance);`

Comment: Okay. Thanks guys :). -6 votes :( too bad

Comment: Please get yourself a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Cool great collection. Thanks

Comment: please read a useful book instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`::` is the *scope resolution operator*, used for referencing static class members and namespace elements.

`->` is the ***indirect*** reference operator, used for referencing members methods and fields on an instance pointer.

`.` is the ***direct*** reference operator, used for referencing member methods and fields on an instance.

Since Java has no real pointers, it has no use for the **indirect** reference operator.

Comment: Java has pointers, but it doesn't provide the programmer with faculties for pointer manipulations - Java handles it all for you.

Comment: Technically they're more like references, but I added a 'real' before pointers in the answer for you ;)

Comment: Also note that static class members can be accessed from an instance, using the dot operator.

Answer (score 4):

The operator `->` is used when you have a pointer to an object and *dereference* the pointer, i.e.

```
string* str = new string("Hello, World");
const char* cstr = str->c_str();
```

whereas

```
string str("Hello World");
const char* cstr = str.c_str();
```

is used to directly reference a member.

The `::` is the "scope-operator". You can use it to call `static` members of a class or reference a member in a `namespace`.

```
namespace X{
 int a;
}

int main() {
...
X::a = 4;
...
}
```

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) on this.